# Rotating set of line segments to create 3D mesh

Tags: graphics3d, rotation

I have a set of line segments

```
h = 4; w = 2; t = 1;
lineSegments = Line[{{0, 0}, {w, 0}, {w, h}, {w + t, h}, {w + t, -h - t}, {w, -h - t}, {w, -t}, {0, -t}}];
Graphics[lineSegments]
```

[image]

Now I want to rotate them around the axis `x = 0` and create 3D mesh similar to what `RevolutionPlot3D[]` does to parametric functions. How can I achieve this?

Comment: The cleanest way would problaby be `BooleanRegion`: Subtracting two small `Cylinder`s from a large `Cylinder`.

Answer (score 1):

Something like the following might do in your particular case:

```
opts = {MaxCellMeasure -> 0.01};
RegionDifference[
 DiscretizeRegion[Cylinder[{{0, 0, 4}, {0, 0, -5}}, 3], 
  Sequence @@ opts],
 RegionUnion[
  DiscretizeRegion[Cylinder[{{0, 0, 5}, {0, 0, 0}}, 2], 
   Sequence @@ opts],
  DiscretizeRegion[Cylinder[{{0, 0, -1}, {0, 0, -6}}, 2], 
   Sequence @@ opts]
  ]
 ]
```

[image]